# Dynamic routerLink in Angular application not returning correct result

Tags: angular

I have a button which calls a dynamic routerlink in my Angular application:

```
<a [routerLink]="goTo()" type="button">
    Go To
</a>
```

In my component:

```
readonly baseUrl = `http://my.company.com/;

goTo() {
    return `${this.baseUrl}Job/Notes`
}
```

What this does though is append my string to the back of my current URL, so end up as:

> http://my.company.com/mycurrentroute/http:/my.company.com/Job/Notes

Note sure why it removes a slash as well from my baseUrl

What am I doing wrong?  The correct response should be 'http://my.company.com/Job/Notes'

Comment: your routerLink has no opening bracket.

Comment: Sorry, that was a code formatting issue as I removed my classes to make it more succinct, but the actual code does have the opening bracket. I've updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not append your baseUrl on your goTo() return url. Since RouterLink already targets the current baseUrl upon running your application so by default it will target:

`http://my.company.com/`

What you will do is just append its sub routes example:

```
goTo() {
   return './Job/Notes';   // May it be "/Job/Notes"
}
```

Or you can specify it directly on the routerLink:

```
<a [routerLink]="['./Job/Notes']" type="button">    // "./" pertains to the current parent route with the baseUrl
    Go To
</a>
```